# How to verify that an element is present in CucumberJS and Protractor?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, cucumberjs

I want to verify that an element is present when I access a page using the above mentioned FWs, is there any similar assertion library for these like the one that exists in Jasmine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`protractor` actually [documents](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/frameworks#using-cucumber) how to configure `protractor` to work with `cucumber` framework. You need to add:

```
framework: 'cucumber'
```

to your protractor config and use a separate assertion library to deal with resolving promises while making your expectations. Here is an [example](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/cucumber/stepDefinitions.js) that uses [`chai-as-promised`](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/) plugin to [`Chai` assertion library](http://chaijs.com/). That said and based on that, here is how you can assert an element is present:

```
expect(element(by.id('myid')).isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true;
```

`eventually` here is that "magic" that implicitly [resolves promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30790425/771848).

---

Note that *`CucumberJS` and `Jasmine` are mutually exclusive*, see:

- [How to use Jasmine and CucumberJS with Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740824/how-to-use-jasmine-and-cucumberjs-with-protractor)